# Can webpack watch for changes in .php files?

Tags: php, webpack-2, file-watcher

Let's say I have a file structure like:

[image: Directories]

I'd like webpack command to watch for changes in the src/functions.php and implement them in the dist/functions.php. Basically all it needs to do is copy and paste if there are any changes.

Is this something webpack is able to do? Do I need any loaders or plugins for that?

Comment: You can use copy-webpack-plugin for this use case:  https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Copy Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) for this use case.